# how to subscribe float32 data

Tags: ros, gazebo, subscribe, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to subscribe gazebo topics and see the datas on a webpage.

```
var cmdSonarTopic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
ros : ros,
name : '/gazebo/sensor/Sonar0',
messageType : 'sensor_msgs/Range' });

cmdSonarTopic.subscribe(function(message) {
console.log('Received message on ' + cmdSonarTopic.name + ': ' +  message.header.range);   });
```

But on browser console the message i see is "Received message on /gazebo/sensor/Sonar0: undifined ". Range's data type is float32. How can i make it right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209114/how-to-subscribe-float32-data/) by [minerva](https://answers.ros.org/users/21509/minerva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sorry guys its my mistake. range data should be out of header scope.

---

Originally posted by [minerva](https://answers.ros.org/users/21509/minerva/) with karma: 18 on 2015-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0